# Rails HABTM self join error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my application a user can follow many users and can be followed by many users.
I tried to model this using has_and_belongs_to_many association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "followee_id", join_table: "followees_followers"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followees, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "follower_id", join_table: "followees_followers"
end
```

Also, I created a migration for join table as follows:

```
class FolloweesFollowers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table 'followees_followers', :id => false do |t|
        t.column :followee_id, :integer
        t.column :follower_id, :integer
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table 'followees_followers'
  end
end
```

when I try to access followers of a user (User.first.followers) it throws an error:

```
SQLException: no such column: followees_followers.user_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "followees_followers" ON "users"."id" = "followees_followers"."user_id" WHERE "followees_followers"."followee_id" = 1
```

I don't understand why is it accessing followees_followers.user_id. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The :foreign_key and [:association_foreign_key](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-foreign-key) options are useful when setting up a many-to-many self-join.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "followee_id", join_table: "followees_followers", association_foreign_key: "follower_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followees, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "follower_id", join_table: "followees_followers", association_foreign_key: "followee_id"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear that it would try to access a `user_id` field since you are accessing the relationship from an instance of the `User` class.

Try setting `:association_foreign_key => "follower_id"` in your `followers` relationship and setting `:association_foreign_key => "followee_id"` in your `followees` relationship.